# How to solve undefined method `model_name' with polymorphic devise user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for registration, with Rails 4 and Ruby 2
I've defined a User model, which has a polymorphic association with either a Speaker or Organization (I didn't program this model yet). I have created my own Devise RegistrationController for initializing the appropriate object (Speaker) when initializing a User object. According to a special route. i've edited the new registration form with fields for the Speaker object. **What I want to achieve is that when the user fills in all the fields (fields from User and fields from Speaker), that a appropriate object is created. Thus, a User object with a link to the Speaker object. But when I submit the form I got the following error**, but instead I got the following error, with my current implementation:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Extracted source (around line #35):

```
<%=
fields_for resource.identifiable do | identifiable_fields |
render "#{resource.identifiable.class.name.downcase}_fields", f: identifiable_fields
end
%>
```

The models are as follows:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :identifiable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

```rb
class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :user, as: :identifiable

    validates :first_name, :presence => true, length: { in: 2..20 }
    validates :last_name,  :presence => true, length: { in: 2..20 }

    def full_name
        [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
    end

    def full_name_reverse
        [last_name, first_name].join(', ')
    end
end
```

UserRegistrationsController:

```rb
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    # Devise RegistrationsController override.
    # version 3.2.3

    def new
         head :not_implemented and return unless is_identifiable_name?(params[:identifiable_name])
         build_resource_with_identity({},params[:identifiable_name])
         respond_with self.resource
    end

    def create
        build_resource(sign_up_params)
        puts sign_up_params
        if resource.save
            yield resource if block_given?
            if resource.active_for_authentication?
                set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
                sign_up(resource_name, resource)
                respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
            else
                set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
                expire_data_after_sign_in!
                respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
            end
        else
            clean_up_passwords resource
            respond_with resource
        end
    end


    private

    def build_resource_with_identity(hash = nil, identifiable_name)
        self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
        self.resource.identifiable = identifiable_name.downcase.camelize.constantize.new
    end

    def is_identifiable_name?(identifiable_name)
       ['speaker'].include? identifiable_name.downcase
    end

end
```

Route for the UserRegistrationsController#new

```rb
get 'speakers/register', to: 'user_registrations#new', defaults: { identifiable_name: 'speaker' }, as: :new_speaker_registration
```

New user registration form:

```rb
<h2>Registreren</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-3 columns">
            <%= f.label :email, 'Email', class: "right inline" %>
        </div>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="small-3 columns">
           <%= f.label :password, 'Wachtwoord', class: "right inline" %>
       </div>
       <div class="small-9 columns">
           <%= f.password_field :password, :autofocus => true %>
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="small-3 columns">
           <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Bevestig wachtwoord', class: "right inline" %>
       </div>
       <div class="small-9 columns">
           <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :autofocus => true %>
       </div>
   </div>

    <%=
        fields_for resource.identifiable do | identifiable_fields |
            render "#{resource.identifiable.class.name.downcase}_fields", f: identifiable_fields
        end
    %>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-9 small-offset-3">
            <%= f.submit "Registreren", class: "small button radius" %>
        </div>
    </div>

<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Speaker fields partial:

```rb
      <div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns">
        <%= f.label :first_name, 'Voornaam', class: "right inline" %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-9 columns">
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, :autofocus => true %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns">
        <%= f.label :last_name, 'Achternaam', class: "right inline" %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-9 columns">
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, :autofocus => true %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Logs:

Application trace:

```
app/views/user_registrations/new.html.erb:35:in `block in _app_views_user_registrations_new_html_erb___3888261175776937705_70060949603300'
app/views/user_registrations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_user_registrations_new_html_erb___3888261175776937705_70060949603300'
app/controllers/user_registrations_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

Parameters sent:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"vDLeKE+CJvzZa/GDcE9KqvV8jszWhc5uPBvBgBkTjO0=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "speaker"=>{"first_name"=>"",
 "last_name"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Registreren"}
```

Comment: `resource.identifiable` is nil in your view - where is that being set?

Comment: @sevenseacat in the method `build_resource_with_identity` in the UserRegistrationsController. this is the line: `self.resource.identifiable = identifiable_name.downcase.camelize.constantize.new`

Comment: is the error coming on rendering the form or submitting the form? Can we see some logs?

Comment: @sevenseacat The error is coming when I submit the form. What logs exactly?

Comment: The stacktrace logs from your browser or your terminal window. You're calling your `build_resource_with_identity` in your new action, but not create - if it's then trying to re-render the form, then `resource.identifiable` may be nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem of the undefined method:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

As mentioned by member sevenseacat, when submitting the form, `resource.identifiable` is `nil` in the *create* method of *UserRegistrationsController*. The solution is to make sure that `resource.identifiable` is set with the appropriate object in the `create` method, as I'm making use of a polymorphic association at the *User* model. So for example, If I want to register a *Speaker*, `User.identifiable` (User is the devise model) must return a *Speaker* object.

---

**Please note that when writing the solution, I've rewritten/optimized some code comparing to the code that I posted in my answer.**

---

First, I changed my **routes.rb**.
I've given the name of the model it should associate with the User model in the defaults hash.

```
get 'speakers/register', to: 'user_registrations#new', defaults: { identifiable_type: 'Speaker' }, as: :new_speaker_registration

get 'organizations/register', to: 'user_registrations#new', defaults: { identifiable_type: 'Organization' }, as: :new_organization_registration
```

---

In **user_registrations_controller.rb** I changed a couple of things.

**new method**
In the `new` method, I'm checking if the parameter that comes within the defaults hash, had either the value *Speaker* or *Organization*, to make sure that are the only values allowed.
After the usual *User* object is build, I am building the appropriate identifiable (*Speaker* or *Organization*) object by calling `constantize` and then `new`.

**create method**
In the create method, devise will build the User object with its parameters.
Then, I'm fetching the name of the object that needs to be associated with the *User* object. The name of the object is passed in via the form. Then this name is constantized so `new` can be called on it.

in Rails 4 mass-assignment isn't allowed by default. You have to specify which attributes are allowed. With the method `identifiable_resource_params`, I'm checking which parameters to pass in, according to the name of the object.

---

```
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    # Devise RegistrationsController override.
    # version 3.2.3

    def new 
         head :not_implemented and return unless is_identifiable_type?(params[:identifiable_type])
         build_resource
         self.resource.identifiable = params[:identifiable_type].constantize.new       
         respond_with self.resource
        end

    def create
        build_resource(sign_up_params)
        identifiable_type = params[:user][:identifiable_type].to_s
        resource.identifiable = identifiable_type.constantize.new(identifiable_resource_params(identifiable_type))
        if resource.save
            yield resource if block_given?
            if resource.active_for_authentication?
                set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
                sign_up(resource_name, resource)
                respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
            else
                set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
                expire_data_after_sign_in!
                respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
            end
        else
            clean_up_passwords resource
            respond_with resource
        end
    end

    private

    def is_identifiable_type? identifiable_type
        ['Speaker','Organization'].include? identifiable_type
    end

    def is_speaker_type? identifiable_type
        'Speaker'.eql?(identifiable_type)
    end

    def is_organization_type? identifiable_type
        'Organization'.eql?(identifiable_type)
    end

    def identifiable_resource_params identifiable_type
        if is_speaker_type? identifiable_type
            params.require(identifiable_type.underscore.to_sym).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
        elsif is_organization_type? identifiable_type
            params.require(identifiable_type.underscore.to_sym).permit(:name, :description, :category, :contact_first_name, :contact_last_name, :contact_email)
        end
    end

end
```

---

In **new.html.erb** I added two things. 
The first is some code, for rendering the appropriate partial which contains specific fields for either a *Speaker* or *Organization* object. Secondly, I made sure the name of the object that needs to be associated with a *User* object is passed through, so the `create` method in the controller has knowledge about it.